# How do I repeat the "resize window" command in vim?

Tags: vim

I know how to resize a window (`CTRL_W +`). But when I want to repeat the same command, `.` is useless. Typing `CTRL_W +` repeatedly is boring. Is there anything else I can do?

In my system:

```
if bufwinnr(1)
  map + <C-W>+
  map - <C-W>-
endif
```

does not work.

```
if bufwinnr(1)
  map <kPlus> <C-W>+
  map <kMinus> <C-W>-
  map <kDivide> <c-w><
  map <kMultiply> <c-w>>
endif
```

does work.

Comment: Please see [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/) on vi.stackexchange.com offers some solutions, including configuring the submode and repmo plugins to do this.

Comment: Look a a full configuration with submodule (very very light): https://ddrscott.github.io/blog/2016/making-a-window-submode/

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend the mapping of `+` and `-` key like this (in your `.vimrc`):

```
if bufwinnr(1)
  map + <C-W>+
  map - <C-W>-
endif
```

And please read this, there are several good tips: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fast_window_resizing_with_plus/minus_keys

Comment: In my system:

    if bufwinnr(1)
      map + <C-W>+
      map - <C-W>-
    endif

is not worked.

    if bufwinnr(1)
      map <kPlus> <C-W>+
      map <kMinus> <C-W>-
      map <kDivide> <c-w><
      map <kMultiply> <c-w>>
    endif

is worked, thanks all:)

Comment: This is great; although what would be REALLY great is if somebody added window resizing to this plugin: http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=2174

Answer (score 6):

The <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> shortcut takes a preceding count.  The <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> command maximizes the window without a count, or sets absolute height with a preceding count.  Using counts, you should rarely have to do repeated window resizing commands.

If you do find yourself frequently wanting to make small repeated adjustments to window sizes, maybe you could take advantage of the repeatability of ex-commands (with `@:`) and resize with `:resize +1` instead of the keyboard shortcut.  If you resize windows all the time, I'd go with mapping the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> as Zsolt [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952636/how-to-repeat-the-resize-window-command-in-vim/6952698#6952698).  If you are just restoring the same window layout over and over, look into using a saved session file (`:help sessions`).

Comment: You can use `:res-1` and `:res+1` to type a bit less.